# Python edit file with an insanely long line

Tags: python-2.6

I am trying to edit particular html files that I download in python. I am running into a problem where I run my code to edit the file and my python context locks up. I checked the file it's writing to and found that there are two files. The html file and a .bak file.

The html file starts out at 0kb and the .bak file constantly grows to a point, maybe 12 mb or so, then the .html file will grow to a larger size, then the .bak file will grow again. This seems to cycle endlessly. The html file I am editing is 22kb. I watched the output file grow to a gig once just to see if it would stop... It doesn't.

Here is the function I am using to edit the file:

```
def replace(self, search_str, replace_str):
    f = open(self.path,'r+')
    content = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(content):
        content[i] = line.replace(search_str, replace_str)
    f.writelines(content)
    f.close()
```

The issue, I imagine relates to the fact that the html file, as downloaded, is mostly in a single line with ~ 21,000 characters in it. Any ideas?

edit:

I have also tried another function, but get the same result:

```
def replace(self, search_str, replace_str):
    assert self.path != None, 'No file path provided.'
    fi = fileinput.FileInput(self.path,inplace=1)
    for line in fi:
        if search_str in line:
             line=line.replace(search_str,replace_str)
        print line
    fi.close()
```

Comment: If you look in the output file, does anything strike you as being wrong? Have you determined that it works for files with smaller lines?

Comment: unfortunately due to the length of the line I cannot open the file to view it. I have verified that the code works fine with files that have fewer lines.

Comment: Any competent text editor should be able to open it. Just don't let the file get really large before halting your program, for convenience in opening time. Even Notepad will open a 39MB one-line text file after a while. I imagine vi or Emacs would also have no problem.

Comment: turning on word-wrap in n++ allowed me to open the files. You're right it is very strange. Both the .bak file and the /html file are just appending empty lines endlessly...

Comment: That suggests that maybe you shouldn't modify `line` in the loop (because it is the iterator variable).

Comment: I tried modifying the code to use a "new_line" variable instead of the iterator variable, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote the function to write everything out to a new file and it works.

```
def replace(self, search_str, replace_str):
    f = open(self.path,'r+')
    new_path = self.path.split('.')[0]+'.TEMP'
    new_f = open(new_path,'w')
    new_lines = [x.replace(search_str, replace_str) for x in f]
    new_f.writelines(new_lines)
    f.close()
    new_f.close()
    os.remove(self.path)
    os.rename(new_path, self.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using generator. Thats the way to go if you need to read a large file

```
for line in open(self.path,'r+'):
    # do stuff with line
```